# How to make subscripts and superscripts using NSAttributedString?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsattributedstring

I need to make subscripts for chemistry formulas (H2O, Na^2+, etc)?

Is this possible to do with NSAttributedString, or is there an alternative/easier way to make subscripts?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is possible to do with `NSAttributedString`. The attribute constant you're looking for depends on your platform. For Mac OS X it is `NSSuperscriptAttributeName` and on iOS it is `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName`. Pass in a negative value for subscript.

The only caveat is that `UILabel` on iOS can't draw `NSAttributedString`s (yet, fingers crossed for iOS 6). You would need to draw the text using Core Text or find some third party replacement for `UILabel` that can draw an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Thanks. Can you use kCTSuperscriptAttributeName to make superscripts as well?

Comment: Yes as I stated, a positive value is for superscripts. A negative value for subscripts.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how I missed that. Thanks again.

Comment: It should be noted that `UILabel` supports `NSAttributedString` via the `attributedString` property by now. Values of `kCTSuperscriptAttributeName` can also be decimal values between `-1`and `1` to change the super/subscripted text position to whatever fits you.

Answer (score 34):

Here's what I did in iOS 6. First add the CoreText, and QuartzCore frameworks. Then import:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <CoreText/CTStringAttributes.h>
#import <CoreText/CoreText.h>
```

I made a small function that inputs a plain NSString and exports a NSMutableAttributedString with the last character in superscript. This can be modified to allow setting superscript or subscript, change kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value to -1. Also you could add a variable to specify where to put the superscript in the string. Right now it just assumes the end of the string.

```
- (NSMutableAttributedString *)plainStringToAttributedUnits:(NSString *)string;
{
    NSMutableAttributedString *attString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:string];
    UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:10.0f];
    UIFont *smallFont = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0f];

    [attString beginEditing];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(font) range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length - 2)];
    [attString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:(smallFont) range:NSMakeRange(string.length - 1, 1)];
    [attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@"1" range:NSMakeRange(string.length - 1, 1)];
    [attString addAttribute:(NSString*)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor blackColor] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length - 1)];
    [attString endEditing];
    return attString;
}
```

Now when I want to use it I can do the following to put it in a UITextField:

```
    NSString *qlwUnitsPlainText = @"m3";
    self.quantityLoadWeightUnits_textField.attributedText = [self plainStringToAttributedUnits:qlwUnitsPlainText];
```

I hope this helps somebody else, there's not many examples out there!

Comment: Can you please take a look at this part of the attributedString: https://gist.github.com/mladjan/6663691
Doesn't want to render superscript :(

Comment: You should not that NSMakeRange parameters are firstPosition and length (instead of firstPosition and lastPosition). In the example the reader may be mislead.

Comment: how can i remove it

Answer (score 9):

On iOS, I had missed the kCTSuperscriptAttributeName constant but had good results with font size and "baseline". It gives you a little more control too for less obedient fonts:

```
+ (NSAttributedString *)attributedStringForText:(NSString *)normalText andSuperscript:(NSString *)superscriptText textSize:(CGFloat)textSize
{
    UIFont *normalFont = [Styles mainFontWithSize:textSize];
    UIFont *superFont = [Styles mainFontWithSize:textSize / 2];

    NSMutableAttributedString *finalStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:normalText attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: normalFont}];

    NSAttributedString *superStr = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:superscriptText attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName: superFont, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:@(textSize/2)}];

    [finalStr appendAttributedString:superStr];

    return finalStr;
}
```

Comment: what is `Styles` here ?

Comment: @AadilKeshwani Just a static class to centralise fonts, sizes, colours, and other styles related to the app.

Comment: @AadilKeshwani Styles is just a static class acting as a stylesheet, centralising most of the style constants in the app.

Answer (score 1):

> For SubScript use value for kCTSuperscriptAttributeName as @-1.
>
> As per the document
>
> @discussion Value must be a CFNumberRef. Default is int value 0. If
>   supported
>                   by the specified font, a value of 1 enables superscripting and a
>                   value of -1 enables subscripting.
>
> extern const CFStringRef kCTSuperscriptAttributeName
>   CT_AVAILABLE(10_5, 3_2);

```
 Example- [lblHeader setText:@“Headers [Alpha1 – text”];

        NSMutableAttributedString *headerSubscript = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithAttributedString: lblHeader.attributedText];

        [headerSubscript addAttribute:(NSString *)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName value:@-1 range:NSMakeRange(14,1)];      

        [lblHeader setAttributedText:headerSubscript];
```

Comment: @Bhargav Rao It is in swift, thats why i've wrote this answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do the following if you want to make it a litle cleaner

```
NSDictionary *attr = @{ NSFontAttributeName: smallfont, 
                        (NSString*)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName: @1 }

NSRange fabricWeightRange = NSMakeRange(fabricWeight.location + 2, 1);                   
[subKeyString setAttributes:attr range:fabricWeightRange];
```