# Is it possible to adjust the baseline in NSAttributedString?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, ios6, core-text, nsattributedstring

I'd like to slightly modify the y position of a character in an `NSAttributedString`. I know I can [subscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555735/how-to-make-subscripts-and-superscripts-using-nsattributedstring) (or superscript) using the attribute dictionary:

```
@{(id)kCTSuperscriptAttributeName: @(-1)}
```

Unfortunately the shift caused by this is too large in my case. I'm looking for an option to adjust the baseline in 1-point steps.

The attributed string will be displayed in a `UIButton` using `-setAttributedTitle:forState:`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As of iOS 7 the [`NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nsbaselineoffsetattributename) attribute has been added.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can... but only if you draw the text yourself like I am doing it in my DTCoreText open source project.

See line 924ff in DTCoreTextLayoutFrame.m here: https://github.com/Cocoanetics/DTCoreText/blob/master/Core/Source/DTCoreTextLayoutFrame.m

Unfortunately that's the ONLY way I know how to. UIKit does not give you this option.