# How do I make a piece of a NSString superscript

Tags: ios, objective-c, superscript

I'm currently working in **Xcode** with **objective-c**.

I have an normal NSString with a string.
Let's say the string is "Hello Stackoverflow".
Now I want to make the "Hello" piece of the string superscript, how do I do that?

**UPDATE:**

I want to display it in a UItextview. I tried kCTSuperscriptAttributeName from the other post, but the UItextview won't allow "NSmutableattributedstring" or "NSattributedstring".

Comment: A casual NSString does not support such functions. You need an NSAttributedString. Please see the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8555735/how-to-make-subscripts-and-superscripts-using-nsattributedstring

Comment: `NSString` has no notion of formatting. Are you trying to display this string in e. g. a `UILabel` or `UITextView`? Then you could use `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: Where are you displaying your `NSString`?

Comment: I want to display it in a UItextview.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Well you can't as `NSString` only holds characters, not attributes about how those characters will be displayed.

That answers the question, however my answer can be enhanced if you tell us how you intend to display the string.