# Adding/Appending Attributed text to label in Swift 3 - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

Im trying to add attributed text infront of label at upper right position in swift 3 like [PDF] in picture shown

[image: Please check screen shot]

My requirement is... I have a picker view which has text values with list of countries..when a value is selected, I need to show that country name along with its Continent.

I am able show picker view value selected in label which is simple but not sure how to append continent name at upper right position

If I select USA, my label should show NA USA (where NA is North America) with NA in the place of [PDF] and USA in place of "this is sample PDF" from attachment

I can display that by adding uiView in front of label but my requireent clearly says not to add uiview to display this. This should be uilabel with text changing dynamically

Not sure how i can use attributed string to label here

Please guide

Comment: Have you made any attempt to use `NSMutableAttributeString` and the label's `attributedText` property?

Comment: I'm not sure how I can display my continents..I could add reference links with NSMutableAttributeString..but how to position it on upper right hand is puzzling me

Comment: so as you said not to add UIview, not even two labels?

Comment: This worked like charm. Extension for sub and superscript http://stackoverflow.com/a/37614145/6347717

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code for that

Output will be 27.67 where .67 will show small and 27 will show large

```
    let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "27.67", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:Typography.largeDrawerSavingAmountLabel!])
    attString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:Typography.smallDrawerSavingAmountLabel!,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:33], range: NSRange(location:attString.string.characters.count - 2,length:2))
    lblTotalAmount.attributedText = attString;
```

Where

You put your font at place of `Typography.largeDrawerSavingAmountLabel`
and `Typography.smallDrawerSavingAmountLabel`

Comment: Thanks Mike. But I was looking other way around. To align first two characters on top left and rest in bottom..I found this which worked to meet requirement.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/37614145/6347717