# How to set 1st, 2nd and 3rd letters above the digit in swift

Tags: ios, swift3, uilabel

I want to set text like 12th 3rd 1st in a `UILabel`. but 2 letters should be appeared above the digit.Please help me.
Thanks

**[image: UPDATE]**

Comment: May you please add an example of what you want?

Comment: its something like 10^3

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed pls see the image I added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This function should do exactly what you are looking for:

```
func prepareLabel(label: UILabel, string: String, superScript: String) {

    let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:20)
    let fontSuper = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:10)

    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string + superScript, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font!])
    attributedString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:fontSuper!, NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:10], range: NSRange(location:string.characters.count, length:superScript.characters.count))
    label.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Usage:

```
prepareLabel(label: self.label, string: "15", superScript: "th")
```

This function was inspired by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31125169/4763963), take a look at it for more information.

Good luck!