# how to display product price as superscript in swift 3

Tags: swift3

i need to display product price as amazon using swift 3. I have tried normal superscripting. But it is not in same alignment. i need exactly as in amazon website along with dollar symbol.
 i tried this code..
 var amountArray = String(format: "%.2f", item.savedAmount).components(separatedBy: ".")

```
          let font:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:18)
    let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:13)
    let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "$ \(amountArray[0])\(amountArray[1])", attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:font!])
    attString.setAttributes([NSFontAttributeName:fontSuper!,NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName:10], range: NSRange(location:amountArray[0].characters.count+2,length:2))

    purchaseAmount.attributedText = attString
```

Comment: post your code so that we get to know what you have tried

Comment: Are you trying to use an amazon product feed or just scraping the website?

Comment: No..for my app I need to display product name just like amazon site.

Comment: may be this will help you [subscript-and-superscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29225779/how-to-use-subscript-and-superscript-in-swift)